# Can't install certain firefox extensions using Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I attempt to install Firefox extensions using Selenium on Python, I receive a `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` error for about 50% of the extensions that i attempt to install. For example, when I try to install the latest version of firebug, with the command:

```
 firefox_profile.add_extension(working_director + "\\firebug-2.0.11-fx.xpi")
```

I get the error:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 265, in _install_extension
with open(os.path.join(tmpdir, name), 'wb') as f:
 IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\USERNAME\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpxu73xr.firebug-2.0.11-fx.xpi\\content/firebug/'
```

(n.b. this does not happen with version 2.0.9 of firebug, which works fine)

I get similar errors when trying to install quickjava (quickjava-2.0.6-fx), and imageblock (imageblock-2.1-fx). I suspect the error originates in the `/` which is at the end of the install path (as opposed to `\\` elsewhere) i.e. `...temp\\tmpxu73xr.firebug-2.0.11-fx.xpi\\content/firebug/`.

Can't understand why i don't have problems with some extensions. Looking for a work-around for those which don't work. For reference, I am using Firefox 39, and Selenium 2.46.0 on Windows

Comment: Can you try moving the `xpi` from inside the `appdata` and point `add_extension()` directly to the file? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe - sorry slightly confused by what you are suggesting (for reference, the location that the file is installing from is not in appdata)

Comment: Okay. Try moving the xpi into a different location..

Comment: @alecxe - changed to `firefox_profile.add_extension("C:\\firebug-2.0.11-fx.xpi")` - still results in exactly the same error message.

Comment: Have you tried running your script under administrative mode? It looks like you don't have permissions.

Comment: @sandwichheat yep - running as administrator - as note some extensions install without problems, others not. It seems like installation gets half way through (i.e. some files are created in the folder, `...temp\\tmpxu73xr.firebug-2.0.11-fx.xpi\` before it throws up error).

Comment: Thanks - @sandwichheat - your prior answer on bug 734 - led me to solve problem (although it is still an issue in the most stable release).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With thanks to @sandwich Heat who initially posted part of the answer (before he/she or someone else deleted it) - this was a bug with Salenium - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/734

This issue is fixed on the the github page https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py but as of yet is not in the stable release of Selenium (2.46.0)

I thus solved my problem by replacing the file `firefox_profile.py` with that on Github.